# Replace the node-edit menu in Drupal

Tags: drupal, menu

How can I change (unset or add) a new button in my `edit`-node menu? In this case, I would like to diable the 'Settings'-menu and add a new menu... I looked in the `$form` and the `$form_state`, but no luck there. At least, that's what I think...

[image]

**EDIT**

**Module name:** publication
**Install:** publication.install
**File:** publication.module

```
function publication_menu_alter(&$items) {
     unset($items['node/%node/edit']);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
function publication_menu() {
    $items['node/add/fiche'] = array(
        'title' => 'New linked fiche',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
    );
    return $items;
}
```

**EDIT 3**
What I'm trying to do is to allow my users to add some more content to existing content. So they are not allowed to edit the current content, only to add some details. So I thought, I delete the `edit`-button and replace it with an `add`-button and the `add`-button links to a page where he can create more content. That's it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `hook_menu_alter` to unset menu.

```
function publication_menu_alter(&$items) {
    // print_r($items);
    // Find path you want to unset then unset it.
    // Should be something like:
    unset($items['your/menu/path']);
}
```

And `hook_menu` for defining new one. In your case I believe it should be menu type `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` since you want to add a new tab. Isn't it?

```
function publication_menu() {
    $items['node/%node/something_else'] = array(
        'title' => 'My title',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_abc_view($nid = NULL) {
    return 'This node ID is '. $nid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but the `hook_menu_alter` is not working right now... Even if I place a `die;` in the function, the page doesn't respond...

Comment: That's really strange. Could you provide your code of menu_alter?
And the name of your module please.

Comment: Ah, I see now why it is like that.
You see, there is no path as `node/13/edit` registered in Drupal. In this case the path is `node/%node/edit` and you can unset only registered path. You see what I mean?

Comment: What is the name of your module?
Please provide your module's folder, **.module and **.info names.

Comment: Hm. Your code seems fine. And I just did it on my side and it works fine. Did you tried to clear cache?

Comment: You should never forget about cache when it's about menu! Always keep that in mind!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! But now, the second function isn't working... :s :) => see my update

Comment: See function `publication_menu()` in my updated answer.
In your case you can't use `type` as `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`. In your case it could be `MENU_CALLBACK` or `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`.
Read more about menu system in Drupal http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal.

Comment: It has to. Clear your cache. Create a node (lets assume it's ID = 5). Go to `node/5/something_else` and you MUST see content as 'test' with 'My title' title. If it doesn't happen, inspect all your code again because it can't work.

Comment: Allright!! It worked. But it's not possible to include an external link? `node/%node/edit` works just fine, but `add/node/fiche` doesn't... Any idea why?

Comment: `add/node/fiche` is static path, you should use menu type as `MENU_CALLBACK` or `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! Is there anyway to limit this on a specific content-type without Drupal asking to do an `if-statement` all the time?

Comment: If you need to do something for a specific thing, you will always use `if-statement`.

Comment: Hm, ok. By the way `MENU_CALLBACK` or `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` didn't work out... The button doesn't appear at all anymore.

Comment: Well button appear only if it's `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`. I'm little bit confused with what you trying to achieve. Maybe you will try to explain it in more details?

Comment: Please take this to a chat-room. The comment system is meant for minor feedback and corrections, not for prolonged discussion. If there is more information required either in the question or the answer, please edit that into the answer, but take the rest of the discussion to a chat-room. Also note that since the answer was accepted over 3 hours ago, either the question is being expanded (which should be posted as a new question instead) or the answer does not actually answer the question, otherwise there would be no point in continuing to edit in more details.